# PHP - SQL structured table based on date

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to create a table in HTML from SQL and PHP data structured like this, for example:

```
23/03 | 24/03 | 25/03

act1  | act2  | act3    
23/03 | 24/03 | 25/03
```

I'll explain better: i have a list of activities, each one has a date and I need to structure the table so that, for example, every activity on 23/03 goes in the first column, activities on 24/03 go in the second column, etc.

Can anyone help?

Plus: I would like to create the table like a school schedule, every activity also has a time (like 9.00) and if between two activities there's no other activities, there should be a space. Is it possible?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: 1) pls do not ask multiple questions in a single question. Makes answering a lot more difficult. 2) SO is not a free coding service. You need to demonstrate what you have done so far to solve your own question and where you got stuck.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. I'm not asking for someone to code it for me, I'm just asking if this is possible to do.

Comment: Yes, both are possible to be done.